# Codifying a Equation for distance between two points

Tags: python-3.x, math, geocoding

I'm working on a project and have been given an equation to use, however, I'm finding it difficult to turn into workable code.

This equation gives the distance between two lat and lon points and returns an approximate distance in kilometres.

[image]
My code for codifying the equations is:

```
def distance_between_two_point(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):

    c = (float(lat1) - float(lat2)**2) + ((float(lon1) - float(lon2))**2)

    # print(c) # Debugging Print
    print(math.sqrt(abs(c)))

    d = (6371 * math.pi/180) * math.sqrt(abs(c))

    return d
```

I had to specify floats on each variable as it threw a type error, even thoe only floats are being parsed to the function.

The results I'm getting from this function don't seem right and are in the thousands. the results should be a float number less than around 10km.

The input for latlon1 and latlon 2 are latitudes between (-35.29, -35.27) and longitudes between (149.105, 149.130).

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is based on a typographical error.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot a bracket.... darn, sorry y'all, didn't notice it even after 5 hours :(

```
def distance_between_two_point(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):

    c = ((float(lat1) - float(lat2))**2) + ((float(lon1) - float(lon2))**2)

    # print(c) # Debugging Print
    print(math.sqrt(abs(c)))

    d = (6371 * math.pi/180) * math.sqrt(abs(c))

    return d
```

Comment: fwiw you don't need `abs(c)` because `c` is the sum of positive (square) numbers.